# Install Fonts (TTF/OTF) during software installation

Tags: fonts, installation, nsis, opentype, truetype

I have an NSIS installer that needs to install a few fonts on the user's computer (some are TTF sone are OTF). I was looking for anything that can support that with no luck.

Does anyone know how to install fonts with NSIS?